# IPv6 black holing packets from a local TCP socket

Tags: c++, linux, networking, routes

I'm developing an application for WAN data optimisation, including SQUID (using TPROXY redirect) for web caching.  The software modifies the TCP options to negotiate parameters with another remote instance of the software (used in the optimisation algorithm).  Since SQUID will establish the TCP connection with the requesting browser and the WAN packets may be sent over an IPSec tunnel the software MUST run between these two components.

I've be able configure the system such that SQUID will correctly handle the LAN side request, and on a cache miss send packets into my software (using a TUN/TAP interface), modify the TCP header (and correct the csum) and send it back into the kernel through a second TUN/TAP interface.

For packets being sent into the WAN after a cache miss:

For IPv4 if I sent rp_filter=2 on the first tap (and manually add the ARP entries) the packets are correctly routed

For IPv6 the kernel seems to black hole the TCP SYN sent from SQUID.  This is a packet associated with a socket created locally, received back into the (same) kernel to be routed out to the WAN.  If I modify the source or destination ports (i.e. make it look like a different socket) of the packet it is correctly routed out the tunnel/interface.

Are there any sysctl parameters / cleverness in iptables that could explain why these packets are dropped and how do I fix it?